# Voltage drop problem using diodes with CNY 70

Tags: diodes

I am trying to build a complex sensor to read black and white colors that has many CNY 70 sensors inside. The schematic I am using for each individual CNY is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flLVPH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I read voltage at Vo, I get approximately 4,2 V for black color and 100 mV for white, which is nice, but I would like to get more accurate, so I changed it for this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuhpGS.png)</sup>

Since the voltage drop of the 1N4007 diode is 0,6 V, the Vo voltage should turn to 3,5-3,6 V for black and 0 V for white. But if I read the V0 using a 1 kΩ resistor between the diode and ground, I get 80 mV and 0 V. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your goal of "accuracy" seems ill-defined. Can you state more precisely what you expect of Vout?

Comment: @glen_geek I expect exactly that: 3,6 V and 0 V. By accuracy I meant trying to get null voltage for white color.

Comment: For black, **no** transmitted IR light should yield Vout=5V. You seem quite willing to accept Vout of 4,2V (a 800mV offset). And you're willing to further compromise 4,2V with a diode drop. For white, you wish to see 0V and are unwilling to accept a 100mV offset caused by saturation of the phototransistor. Perhaps you intend to drive a logic gate input to decide black from white?

Comment: @Jaime_mc2 If you expect 0 V for "white", what would you want if it's even brighter? What is _white_? The sun? The sun at 1 metre?

Comment: Since the opto isn't saturated the same current into 1/50 the resistance (1k vs 47k) is roughly 80mV